# PyQt4 new modul

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtwebkit, qwebview

I want to do some things with the PyQt4 framework. So I decided to do some browser like thing. Here is the code. Its just simple:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.resize(250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Testbrowser')

        exit = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('icons/exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exit.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exit.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.connect(exit, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), QtCore.SLOT('close()'))

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()

        datei = menubar.addMenu('&Datei')
        datei.addAction(exit)

        tools = menubar.addMenu('&Tools')



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://google.de"))
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I think I understood some of the things here. But what I do not understand is, how can I work with new modules here? The MainWindow class inherits from the QtGui.QMainWindow class, thats ok. But what now? Should I create a whole new class which inherits from QWebView?? Kind of like :

```
class newclass(QWebView.QtWebKit):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.QtWebkit.__init__(self)
        ect
```

Or how can I do this without a new class? Or how do I do this in general? I saw a webpage on which the author made a simple browser too. But he imported it in a new programm and made an object out of it and then did some stuff. Do I have to do this, or is there a simpler way? How is this all done in PyQt4? 
Greets
some reference
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebview.html

Comment: I think you need to narrow down your question. It's not clear what you're confused about: modules? PyQT4? QtWebKit? OOP? Program design?

Comment: Hi thx for reply. I think it has something to do with OOP and PyQt4. I want to know if what i wrote is right. And how can i use the QtWebKit without creating a new class and stuff. Just look at the ?? signs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing elements of a module follows a dot notation convention in Python -- e.g. to access QWebView, you should use

```
web = QtWebkit.QWebView()
```

the URL would be

```
QtCore.QUrl("http://google.de")
```

If you want to have all of the names available to you without dot notation, you have to import everything:

```
from PyQt4.QtWebkit import *
```